# Android: Intent in OnActivityResult giving a wrong path

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, uri, onactivityresult

In the android app that I am making a user takes a photo which I want to display him later in few activities. I've come up to "out of memory error" while displaying currently taken photo in an image view, so I decided to use code from http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html to do it efficiently. Here are methods that I'm using:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;


        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

and

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(Uri mUri, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mUri.getPath(), options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mUri.getPath, options);

};
```

I let the user take photo by the method:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(){
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

And then receive taken picture info:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Uri imageUri = null;
        if(data != null){
            imageUri = data.getData();
        }

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.new_photo);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmap(imageUri, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight()));


    }

}
```

My app breaks and I get info: "File not found or no such directory".
I checked what does the imageUri.getPath() give and in my case its:
 "/external/images/media/1777" (which seems quite strange to me because I'm not using SD card) 
and the taken photo is actually saved in "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0052.JPG". Do you have any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: are u using getExternalStorage method?

Comment: No, I'm not using it. The whole thing with taking a photo and displaying it "happens" in methods I wrote.

Comment: ok is ur image saved? you r using emulator right?

Comment: Yes, it is saved, I can display it in "Album". No, I'm not using emulator, I have my phone connected.

Comment: ok u hv 2 issues out of memory and file path issue?

Comment: I had memory issues when I received a Bitmap directly from onActivityResult(…) and then applied it to imageView without any scaling. Now I get 2 times "File not found or no such directory" errors.

Comment: can you tell me what may be image size?

Comment: ok onActivityResult give u bitmap object?

Comment: Yes, I can receive a thumbnail (which I don't want to use due to its low quality) and also I receive bitmap writing:
Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

Comment: The second option gives me OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intent Extra Max limit is `1MB` approx till **gingerbread**..

I found a magic number 86389 in **JellyBean** if you send above this it will throw memory out of exception..

Solution : **Pass Image Uri, dont pass complete bitmap object**

Comment: Hmm that's strange, I'm using Android 4.3. Ok thank you very much, I'll try to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code just before startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri());
```

Where getImageUri() is

```
private Uri getImageUri() {
    // Store image in dcim
    File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/My_App");       
    if(!myDir.exists())
       myDir.mkdir();
    File file = new File(myDir, "MyImage.png");
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    return imgUri;
}
```

Read up [Android official docs regarding this](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) for further clarification.